# Django: How to automatically change a field's value at the time mentioned in the same object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, celery, django-celery

I am working on a django project for racing event in which a table in the database has three fields.

1)Boolean field to know whether race is active or not

2)Race start time

3)Race end time

While creating an object of it,the start_time and end_time are specified. How to change the value of boolean field to True when the race starts and
to False when it ends? How to schedule these activities?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**To automatically update a model field after a specific time, you can use [Celery tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html).**

**Step-1: Create a Celery Task**

We will first create a celery task called `set_race_as_inactive` which will set the `is_active` flag of the `race_object` to `False` after the current date is greater than the `end_time` of the `race_object`.

This task will be executed by `Celery` only if the current time is greater than the race object's `end_time`.

```
@app.task
def set_race_as_inactive(race_object):
    """
    This celery task sets the 'is_active' flag of the race object 
    to False in the database after the race end time has elapsed.
    """

    race_object.is_active = False # set the race as not active 
    race_object.save() # save the race object
```

**Step-2: Call this celery task using [`eta`](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown) argument**

After creating the celery task `set_race_as_inactive`, we need to call this celery task.

We will call this task whenever we save a new `race_object` into our database. So, whenever a new`race_object` will be saved, a celery task will be fired which will execute only after the `end_time` of the `race_object`.

We will call the task using `apply_async()` and pass the `eta` argument as the `end_time` of the `race_object`.

As per [Celery docs,](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown)

> The ETA (estimated time of arrival) lets you set a specific date and
>   time that is the earliest time at which your task will be executed.
>
> The task is guaranteed to be executed at some time after the specified
>   date and time, but not necessarily at that exact time.

```
from my_app.tasks import set_race_as_inactive

class RaceModel(models.Model):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ..
        create_task = False # variable to know if celery task is to be created
        if self.pk is None: # Check if instance has 'pk' attribute set 
            # Celery Task is to created in case of 'INSERT'
            create_task = True # set the variable 

        super(RaceModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the Django's "real" save() method.

        if create_task: # check if task is to be created
            # pass the current instance as 'args' and call the task with 'eta' argument 
            # to execute after the race `end_time`
            set_race_as_inactive.apply_async(args=[self], eta=self.end_time) # task will be executed after 'race_end_time'
```

This checking of `self.pk` with `None` is done so that only in case of new objects creation, a celery task is created. If we don't do this, then for every `.save()` call (either `INSERT` or `UPDATE`) a celery task will be created which we don't want. This will lead to many unnecessary celery tasks waiting to be executed and will overload our celery queues.

The **benefit** of using Celery is that updation of the `is_active` flag will occur automatically in the background asynchronously without you needing to worry about manually updating them. Every time a new race object is created, a task will be fired and Celery will defer its execution until the `end_time` of the race. After the `end_time` has elapsed, Celery will execute that task.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84886/discussion-on-answer-by-rahul-gupta-django-how-to-automatically-change-a-field).

Comment: So when you want to send any object to any function then the objects have to be json serialized

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the following scenarios -

1. You want to be Database independent
2. Once a race ends it never start again, so once `active` is `false` it will never be `true` again.

There are numerous ways you can set that true automatically depending on your need -

If you need only when using the object, you can use a property -

```
@property
def active(self):
    return self.end_date > datetime.datetime.utcnow() //I used local time if you want
```

you can also put it in the init -

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.active = self.end_date > datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

But this does not give you the option to perform query, because value is calculated after object is loaded in memory.

If you want to perform query, so we need to update the value in the database and save it. Assuming that when the race ends, you update the date in the overridden save method -

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.active = self.end_date > datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    super().save()
```

So when you save the object after the race ends, it will update the flag.

But if it is not possible for you to update the race when it ends and you need them to be calculated automatically you could use a scheduler. Like `Celery` as @rahul suggested to update periodically. But for this option, you have to accept the fact that, the `active` flag will not be updated at the exact time of the game ends. It will depend on how frequently you run the scheduler.

Comment: Will this work for around 100k races ? Means about the efficiency.

Comment: Yep, I have a similar scenario and it inputs 1k transaction per day.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that your "active" field should be a method instead like this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
class Race(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    def active(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        if self.start < now and now < self.end:
            return True
        return False
```

If you are using Django 1.7+ or South with older versions, this is a trivial change and will normalise your database too, unless the "active" field was intentionally created.

Comment: Wont it increase the time? Means whenever i query that object(call active function) time checking will be done ?

Comment: Yes, **calling** the method costs, but less than the alternative of using Celery. In addition, it is simple and clean, plus you will end up with a normalised schema for your database. Also consider that unless you use .values or .values_list, you will fetch the datetime fields anyway from the database, and this costs a lot more than the function call.

Comment: So for heavy use is Celery better or this one?

Comment: The important thing is to identify what causes the degrade in performance. If you will be calling the method I described very often and by multiple users, then it makes sense to break normalisation and have active as an attribute of your model, which you will be updating with the Celery code described above. @cold_coder

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you wouldn't just calculate the boolean field in your business logic?  i.e. when you receive a request related to that race, simply check the times and assess whether or not the race is active (for display, analysis), etc.

I'm assuming you won't have high load (one reason for pre-processing) like this.

Comment: Actually there will be around 2-3 millions of objects so I need an efficient way.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest you build a service that queues the races in order of when they're about to start, then a second service that queues the races ending and makes updates in the tables.

It may be easier to do this internal to your database.

Comment: Internal to database? I didn't get it. Can you please elaborate how to implement it exactly?

Comment: You can set up a query to update all the rows every so often (be sure to use indices and a fairly specific WHERE statement to minimize writes).  See this: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent.html

Comment: Its only for PostgreSQL. What about others?

Comment: That's the database I'm most familiar with, I am sure other databases have task schedulers but I would urge you to search for the database of your preference and utilize that information.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the predefined save method like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if start:
        boolean_field = True
        super(YouModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        boolean_filed = False
        super(YouModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How will the boolean_field automatically updated to False when the Real time crosses the end_time mentioned in the object ?