# How to change boolean field "isActual" by date

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in Django Rest Framework. I have this model -

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name='description', db_index=True, max_length=64)
```

In this model, I want to add field "`isActual`", which value equal `True` or `False`.

His value must be `False`, if Post created more than 1 month (check field "`created`").

I don't know how to create it. Is it possible?

Comment: Please don't create a field for this. It makes more sense to define a property, or annotation. Since otherwise you will end up in a lot of "synchronization" problems.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , thank you for your answer! Do you have any idea for realise it?

Answer (score 0):

First, Create BooleanField() and 
Check with current timezone like this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903134/django-how-to-automatically-change-a-fields-value-at-the-time-mentioned-in-the) and try it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your queryset like:

```
from django.utils.timezone import 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Q, Expression

Post.objects.annotate(
    is_actual=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(created__gte=now() - relativedelta(months=1)),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

The `Post` objects that arise from this, will carry an extra attribute `is_actual` that is `True` if the post is younger than one month, and `False` otherwise.

You need to install the [**`python-dateutil`** package [PiPy]](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) first in order to import the [**`relativedelta`** [readthedocs.io]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html), with:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: It's not worked. I did add to my ViewSet and nothing happens.
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(
    is_actual=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(created__gte=now() - relativedelta(months=1)),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )

Comment: Error :
 Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field.

Comment: @TheGreatVY: that normally means that your `Post` object has *no* `created` field.

Comment: Why? Check my question, please. My model Post have 'created' field.

Comment: Well aparently not, since the error exactly means that it can not find a `created` field.

Comment: Hm... Maybe, I see this error, because I added your solution to ViewSet?

Comment: @TheGreatVY: that does not matter. Regardless where you add it, you will construct the same queryset.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's my problem. I did set this to other viewSet :) Okay. So, I did set to Post viewset. So, it's not working. I don't see any errors and my backend display all objects. But I don't see is_actual. Why?

Comment: @TheGreatVY: you need to add a serializer view to your serializer class. (so a boolean field with `is_actual` as name).

Comment: how I can do it? Can you help me, please :)