# Update existing data based on days - DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a problem in my project that is not being able to update a column field based on time. That is, I will insert a data via form and fill in the date field, I want that over the days to update a specific field. For example, if 10 days have passed since I inserted the form in my database, I want that on the 11th I change the status of open order to late. I tried to overwrite the save method but it only works when I edit the form and save, or when I insert the form, but that is not my goal.

models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_lenght = 100)
     data_start = models.DateField(default=date.today)
     status = models.Charfield(
         max_length=50,
         default='Open',
         choices=(
            ('Open', 'Open'),
            ('Late', 'Late'),

)



     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            days_for_late = datetime.timedelta(days=15)
            late = self.data_start + days_for_late
            today = datetime.date.today()
            if today > late:
                self.status = 'Late'
                super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am days stuck in this stage, reading many similar questions here on the site, but I couldn't solve it. And most talk about overwriting the save method, which didn't work for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you trying to do is called **asynchronous task/function/job** - functions that runs on your server without user interactions.

Django version < 3.0 cannot handle this type of functions by itself. And even versions > 3.0 are [not](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/) fully covering async tasks. So you have two options to adapt in your code

1. If you will have more async functions, try to use one of async libs compatible with Django, like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html). Celery has very nice [tutorial](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) on how to easily make your own async task. Or you can use this answer from similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903134/django-how-to-automatically-change-a-fields-value-at-the-time-mentioned-in-the)
2. Another option could be [crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) - a scheduler for execution of files in linux. Just [create custom manage.py command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) with your update status script inside and run it in crontab with your virtual envirement enabled