# Field Boolean is not updating with time

Tags: python, django, date, django-models

I am building a Blog App And I am trying to hide blog posts which are older than seven days so, I am showing blog posts which are newer than 7 days. Then i think i can update the `boolean` if post is older then 7 days.

I made a function in models to update the field after seven days.

BUT The field is not updating.

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

class BlogPosts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_older = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def active(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        # changed 15 seconds for testing
        if date_added > timezone.now() - timedelta(seconds=15):
            is_older = False
```

When someone posts a blogposts then boolean is saving to true and I am trying to set to `False` after `7 days`.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903134/django-how-to-automatically-change-a-fields-value-at-the-time-mentioned-in-the?noredirect=1&lq=1) out

Comment: @RustamGarayev, I already checked this and You will notice that i used it from this BUT still not working. ( I don't want to do `celery task`)

Comment: But celery is a way to go for this kind of tasks..

Comment: @RustamGarayev, I don't want `async` with `celery` without `async` will also do good.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save changes with save() method.

```
def active(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    # changed 15 seconds for testing
    if self.date_added > timezone.now() - timedelta(seconds=15):
        is_older = False
        self.save()
```

if you don't want to save in database you could create a property

```
@property
def active(self):
   return self.date_added > timezone.now() - timedelta(seconds=15)
```

So when you have a object of BlogPosts you can call active property

```
blog_post = BlogPosts.objects.first() 
print(blog_post.active) # this will print True or False
```

Comment: It is still not changing after `15 seconds`

Comment: I edited my answer, consider that with the second form it cannot be used in queries.