# Changing Boolean value after specific time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to set a `Boolean Field` set to `False` after 10 minutes , so created a `function` in `models.py` to change the Boolean Value which are older than 10 minutes.

But the function in `models.py` is not working, It is not changing the Boolean value after 10 minutes.

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_old = models.BooleanField(default=False)


#Function to change Boolean Value to False after 10 minutes
    def active(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        if date_added < timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=10):
            is_bountied = False
            self.save()
```

I am not using anything in views.

**What have i tried ?**

I followed [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903134/django-how-to-automatically-change-a-fields-value-at-the-time-mentioned-in-the) question's Answers and created a `celery task` but it was not working, didn't show any errors.

Than i tried :-

```
@property
def active(self):
    return self.date_added >timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.active = self.end_date > datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

BUT it also didn't update the field

It is still not changing or saving the field.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to check if a post is 10 minutes older or not then you can maintain a field `created_at` in the model.
- While fetching `documents` you can search for `created_at >= current_time + 10 minutes)`